# onWrite trigger for updating RTD branch update time goes into recursion

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i want to update the timestamp of branch any time data is changed on it and I came up with this code

```
if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === 'gameStateUpdateTime') {
  exports.gameStateUpdateTime = functions.database.ref('/gameStates/{id}')
    .onWrite((change, _context) => {
      return change.after.ref.child('updatedAt').set(new Date().getTime());
    });
}
```

however that goes into a bad recursion. Any ideas how to prevent recursion?

Answer (score 0):

So it ended up like this:

```
if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === 'gameStateUpdateTime') {
  exports.gameStateUpdateTime = functions.database.ref('/gameStates/{id}')
    .onWrite((change, _context) => {
      if (change.before.exists() && change.after.exists()) {
        const original = change.before.val();
        const updated = change.after.val();

        if (original.updatedAt != updated.updatedAt) {
          return null;
        }
      }

      return change.after.ref.child('updatedAt').set(new Date().getTime());
    });
}
```

Another solution is to save the date on a different branch.